# mysql result from WHERE and the rest

Tags: mysql, where-clause

assume that I have a table like this

```
table name = myTable
id  
----
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

is there any way to fetch some rows with this query

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE id IN (1,5,7) OR ... ;
```

and in fill the ... with any thing that give me the result for WHERE clause first,
and the rest of the rows after those rows???
somethig like this:

```
1,5,7,2,3,4,6
```

Comment: See ORDER BY FIELD()

Answer (score 3):

You don't do this with a `where`, you do this with an `order by`.  Like this:

```
order by (id in (1, 5, 7)) desc
```

MySQL interprets boolean values as integers, with 0 being false and 1 being true.  The `desc` will put the true values before the false ones.